# Using WildCard in PHP if search program

Tags: php, if-statement, wildcard

this is my code that I've written so far --

```
<?php 
  $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
  $search_link = "http://www.example.com/register_complete.php?user=";

  if($actual_link == $search_link)
  echo "Place your conversion pixel code here"; 
?>
```

The situation is like this - Once a user completes a registration he/she lands on urls like these -

```
http://www.example.com/register_complete.php?user=abcd1234
http://www.example.com/register_complete.php?user=abcd12345
http://www.example.com/register_complete.php?user=abcde123456
```

So what I am trying to achieve is fetch the current url using $_SERVER and then matching it with my sample url which is stored in $search_link if both these match then I wish to display a particular code otherwise the code will not be displayed anywhere else in the website.

I don't know how to use wildcard entries in PHP :(

My mind tells I should have done something like this -

```
http://www.example.com/register_complete.php?user=*
```

Can anyone over here help me regarding this please?

Comment: `strpos($haystack, $needle)`

Comment: @u_mulder I didn't get your hint :( can you please explain your thoughts with an example from the above data?

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated? I bet you can exclude http://www.example.com/register_complete.php, because if it's not this file, it won't load the script anyways, so focus on **?user=abc**

```
if (isset($_GET["user"])) {
   echo "Place your conversion pixel code here";
}
```

You can also try `empty()`

OR if you want to compare it to certain value:

```
if ($_GET["user"] == "abcd1234") {
   echo "Place your conversion pixel code here";
}
```

Comment: So, the method you're suggesting will have an impact in the process of a successful signup. The way I planned it was like this -- After a new user successfully registers for an account he/she will be shown a registration complete page(the place where I intend to place the conversion code) but what you are suggesting will result in the new user successfully registering and then signing up (only then will the conversion code fire up).

So in that case if my site has 500 users each time any1 logs in the conversion code will fire up isn't??

Comment: If you put this code only into **register_complete.php** and show this page only after successful registration, it will fire up only after successful registration.

Comment: Look this register_complete.php doesn't have an unique header! The problem is there! Header.tpl is common for all pages! So, I've to check if its that page from header only

Answer (score 0):

There is a function which could help you with your problem and that is strpos(). Check out the following link:

https://www.php.net/strpos